# How to use maven's repo as my class path when running java -cp

Tags: java, maven

I am running a java application in dir /opt/myApp

And I have all needed jars in /opt/myApp/lib

The cmd I am using is  `java -cp /opt/myApp/lib/* org.my.App`

But every time I re-compiled my codes(a maven project), I need to copy all lib files from workspace to /opt/myApp/lib.

**I am wondering if it's possible to just use maven's repo as my class path to avoid copying all jars manually ?**

My progress so far :

I also have some config files in /opt/myApp/config so I can't run it under maven project directly.

Maybe I can make /opt/myApp a maven project and do something in the pom.xml so I can run the app through maven ?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a solution myself:

create a pom.xml in /opt/myApp like :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                                                                                             
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-App-env</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <properties>
            <org.springframework-version>4.3.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    </properties>
    <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <!-- repositories> <repository> <id>twitter-twttr</id> <url>http://maven.twttr.com/</url> 
            </repository> </repositories -->
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>my</groupId>
                    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <type>test-jar</type>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
              <resources>
                      <resource>
                              <directory>config</directory>
                      </resource>
                      <resource>
                              <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                      </resource>
              </resources>
              <plugins>
                      <plugin>
                              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                              <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                              <version>1.6.0</version>
                              <executions>
                                      <execution>
                                              <id>test</id>
                                              <goals>
                                                      <goal>java</goal>
                                              </goals>
                                      </execution>
                              </executions>
                      <configuration>
                              <mainClass>org.my.App</mainClass>
                      </configuration>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
```

then I can run the application through

```
mvn exec:java
```

and the exec-maven-plugin will generate classpath automatically.